# VB.NET - Display form on screen 2

Tags: vb.net

i have been trying to show a form on a 2nd screen (i.e my project) but without any success. My form have an AXMediaPlayer and another form as an overlay. The code i have been using is:

```
Dim screen As Screen
        'Show the form on second screen
        screen = Screen.AllScreens(1)
        Form1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
        Form1.Location = screen.Bounds.Location + New Point(100, 100)
        Form1.Show()
```

Where the form1 is to be loaded and this:

```
Me.Location = Screen.AllScreens(1).Bounds.Location
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        Form2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
        Form2.Location = screen.Bounds.Location + New Point(100, 100)
        Form2.Show()
```

to show the form2 and to try to show the form1 (i tried that after i failed with the first one) on screen 2 (i.e. 1 as per VB). Any help will certainly be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please be clearer. What code does work? Or does none of your code work? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: @Jens Sir, none of them works, actually my Form (i.e Form 1) should open on the second screen together with Form 2 which is the overlay. Do you get it, sir? Form 2 does open on the second screen but form 1 keeps on opening on the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my error. Actually the windowstate of the form was set at maximised so thats why the window could not open on screen 2. I solved it but adding the maximised code to the form load event. Thanks for all your help guyz